# Google App Engine Deleting Local Data Store

Tags: google-app-engine, pycharm

I'm running GAE locally on my mac with pycharm and periodically it seems to delete my local entity datastore. I'm not really sure what's happening and I've taken to keeping a backup but on my old windows machine this was never an issue.

Is there a way to change the setup so that this doesnt happen?

Comment: It used to happen to me in the past, especially after upgrading the App Engine SDK, but I did not see this problem in a long time. I am using Mac.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify a fixed location for your local datastore by adding the datastore_path option to your startup.

```
dev_appserver.py --datastore_path=/tmp/myapp_datastore myapp
```

Otherwise, the temp location of the datastore may change and will be recreated.